# how to parse json from ActiveModel::Serializer back into objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, active-model-serializers

I've got a bunch of serializers. Now I'd like to turn the JSON back into the original objects for testing. I don't see a way to do that with ActiveModel::Serializers.  Looks like there used to be an from_json method that was deprecated. How are you supposed to do this?

Basically I want to test the round tripping like this:

```
json = WidgetSerializer.new(@widget).to_json
testw = Widget.new
testw.from_json(json) #from_json doesn't exist in ActiveModel::Serializers
@widget.should == testw
```

But the "from_json" method on the model doesn't properly read the json from the serializer because its not in the expected format

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is using either Widget.find() or Widget.find_by(), depending on the attributes you pass to your serializer (and especially if one of them is a unique attribute)

For example if your serializer includes id (the simplest in your case) :

```
   json = WidgetSerializer.new(@widget).to_json
   target_id = JSON.parse(json)[:id]
   test_widget = Widget.find(target_id)
   @widget.should == test_widget
```

Comment: sadly that would get the object from the database, not the json, which would defeat the purpose of the unit test. (I didn't explicitly say its for a unit test, but the ".should ==" is a tip off)

Comment: Of course it does fetch it from the database, otherwise how could it be == ? Even if your from_json method returned a new Widget with exact same attributes, the "id" and "created_at" values would be different. (I realize you ask for a unit test but I don't quite understand what you are testing - that you have not forgotten to include all attributes in the Serializer?)

Comment: yes, I wanted to test that the serializer works. its a complex object with nested child objects.

Comment: I understand (I think your question was not phrased clearly but now I understand).

you should not test equality of objects by creating a test widget, because they would never be the same (id etc). You should define your own comparison method that checks one by one the attributes of your object versus the ones stored in the json